# process a method that does not stop runnable() in java

Tags: java, multithreading, desktop-application

I want to have a method that checks if there's an update in the database every second, if the method found a changes in the database, it will call another method to execute the desired operation.

the problem i am facing is that i want a method that keeps on recurring every second even if it calls another method to execute a block of operation.

how would i done that?

I had already use this code

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                CheckNewRequest();
                System.out.println("rode road rowd rowed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Error CheckNewRequest()", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    };

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

where TimeUnit = 1000, but the problem is it does not recur within the specified amount of time that it is supposed to.

Comment: If at all possible, from a design perspective, it is highly likely you'd be better off with a push notification rather than polling. There was a question on this site a year or two ago about such issues, but can't find it at the moment.

Comment: Can you be more clear about "the problem is it does not recur within the specified amount of time that it is supposed to"?

Comment: i mean, the thread does not recur at exact time interval when the CheckNewRequest() method executes. The CheckNewRequest() executes a long process of operation when there is changes in the database and it affects the interval to recur. 
It is like CheckNewRequest() uses about 2minutes to execute the whole process, and the run() method should keep on recurring at every second without being affected by the 2minutes processing time.

Comment: Get rid of that JOptionPane!  If my computer were displaying *a new dialog every second* whenever the network or database went down, I might very well take a fire axe to it.  (Well, okay, I’d probably just forcibly terminate the process.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a core pool size of 1 (`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`), so you can only execute one thread at a time and waiting executions will go in the queue (the executor will only create new threads if the queue is full) and only execute them when the thread become free again.

I'd suggest changing the core pool size to match the number of parallel threads you need, and you can deduce that from the time the request take, if it takes 5 seconds then when one thread is requesting the other fourth threads that started before him are still running (since you period is of one second) which means you need 5 threads.

Comment: what if the processing time of CheckNewRequest() takes about 2minutes, does it still cater that amount of thread? what would be the best approach for this?

Comment: I would first try to optimize CheckNewRequest() as much as possible, because if you have 120 threads this will slow down your method, you'll need even more threads which will further slow down your method, etc... Else you'll need either to scale your database up (more powerful server, or more servers if your database can be distributed), or your application server.